# C3 chart tick values position

Tags: bar-chart, c3.js

I'm building a chart with c3.js.
This is what I have so far: [Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/li1Yn.png)

It is a chart with horizontal bar, so the x axis is rotated. I would like to change the position of the ticks (tick 1, tick 2, tick 3) to have something like this:
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BG7I.png)

Is this possible to do with c3? I didn't find anything on the references.

Thank you!

Comment: c3 doesn't have built-in params to achieve this. But this can be done by transforming text elements inside c3-axis-x.

Answer (score 0):

I needed such functionality too so I came with the following solution:

- find all top-most bars (bars are represented as `<path>` elements) in the DOM. (top-most, because if you have multiple bars in a category, then you'll want to put the tick above the highest one in the category).
- for each bar found in the previous step: look at `d` attribute of the element and parse the `y` coordinate from it. (the `d` attribute defines how the bar should be drawn and it looks like `M 0,27.4 L503.45454545454544,27.4 L503.45454545454544,67 L0,67 z`, so in this case we interested in `27.4`). Store all the coordinates in array.
- insert container element (`<g>`) into the DOM to hold all ticks together
- for each tick, create `<text>` element and assign the corresponding `y` from the coordinates array as the y attribute.

jsbin: https://jsbin.com/mumuhoq/3/edit?html,js,output